# javascript/jquery onChange function for div.text to update form hidden field value

Tags: javascript, forms, onchange

My Classic ASP cart page uses divs for a quantity selector within a form:

```
<form action="/update-cart/" method="post">
     <div class="quantity-selector detail-info-entry">
           <div class="detail-info-entry-title">Quantity</div>
                       <div class="entry number-minus">&nbsp;</div>
                       <div class="entry number">1</div>
                       <div class="entry number-plus">&nbsp;</div>
          </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

when - or + is clicked the 1 will update as expected. the code to do this is this:

```
$('.number-plus').on('click', function(){
    var divUpd = $(this).parent().find('.number'), newVal = parseInt(divUpd.text(), 10)+1;
    divUpd.text(newVal);
});

$('.number-minus').on('click', function(){
    var divUpd = $(this).parent().find('.number'), newVal = parseInt(divUpd.text(), 10)-1;
    if(newVal>=1) divUpd.text(newVal);
});
```

What is the easiest way to post the content of the div with class "number" above when a form is submitted. Do i use:

```
<input type="hidden" id="Num" name="Num" value="" />
```

Or another way. Either way, how can this be done easily as I cannot get the variable "newVal" to populate the hidden field.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you showing us jquery that does not match your html?

Comment: yeah and that question flies right over my head... sorry, no idea what you mean

Comment: _“uses divs for a quantity selector”_ – great way to f*ck up usability … Why don’t you just use an input field for that in the first place? That way at least the user can input a number manually if the like. Having to click buttons multiple times to reach the desired number is not a very convenient way to input larger numbers. And btw., [`type="number"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#number-state-(type=number)) exists.

Comment: The likelihood of someone increasing this selector to more than 2 is rare due to the nature of what it is being used for

Comment: out of interest though, if it makes it work, i'll use an input field but how would I then change the jquery code to reference the form field instead as I can't get it to maintain the jquery's original intention to change the quantity if I change it. Im not good at JS at all so modifying things is difficult for me at the moment

Comment: @brabstah Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved the problem myself.

I added the following line:

```
$("#Num").val(newVal);
```

To both the jquery functions for the + and - divs as follows:

```
 $('.number-plus').on('click', function(){
var divUpd = $(this).parent().find('.number'), newVal = parseInt(divUpd.text(), 10)+1;
divUpd.text(newVal);
$("#Num").val(newVal);
});
 $('.number-minus').on('click', function(){
var divUpd = $(this).parent().find('.number'), newVal = parseInt(divUpd.text(), 10)-1;
if(newVal>=1) divUpd.text(newVal);
$("#Num").val(newVal);
```

});

I am sure I had tried this but after thought I may have omitted the $ at the beginning. Always something simple in the end

Answer (score 1):

This demo has 2 features of note.

1. The following are done with HTML and inline JS `(e.g. onchange='...)`

   - `<input>`s `.number-minus` and `number-plus`
   - `<output>` `.number` displays the sum of `.number-minus` and `.number-plus`
2. As requested, the sum of `.number-minus` and `.number-plus` is stored in a `<input [hidden]>` named `.secret`. This value was derived from `<output>` value by using jQuery (overkill IMO).  `

```js
$(function() {
  $('#pos, #neg').on('change', function(event) {
    var cnt = $('#counter').val();
    $('#secret').val(cnt);
    console.log('Secret: ' + secret.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>javascript/jquery onChange function for div.text to update form hidden field value</title>
  <meta name="description" content="SO33312004">
  <style>
    .detail-info-entry-title,
    #pos,
    #neg {
      font-variant: small-caps;
    }
    .entry {
      padding: 3px;
      margin: 0 5px;
      width: 48px;
      line-height: 1.6;
      border: 2px solid #00E;
      border-radius: 8px;
      display: table-cell;
    }
    #counter {
      font-weight: 900;
      margin: auto;
      display: table-cell;
      height: 24px;
    }
    #form33312004 {
      color: #0CF;
      background: hsla(180, 100%, 10%, 1);
      width: 33%;
      height: 30%;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      display: table-row;
    }
    .field {
      width: 50px;
      display: table-cell;
    }
    footer {
      font-size: .75em;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<!--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33312004/javascript-jquery-onchange-function-for-div-text-to-update-form-hidden-field-val-->

<body>
  <form id="form33312004" submit="return false" oninput="counter.value = parseInt(pos.value, 10) - parseInt(neg.value, 10)">
    <fieldset class="quantity-selector detail-info-entry">
      <legend class="detail-info-entry-title">Quantity</legend>
      <div class="field">
        <input type="number" id="pos" min="0" max="999" step="any" value="0" class="entry number-plus">
        <label for="pos">Positive</label>
      </div>
      <output for='pos neg' id="counter" name="counter" class="entry number">0</output>
      <div class="field">
        <input type="number" id="neg" min="0" max="999" step="any" value="0" class="entry number-minus">
        <label for="neg">Negative</label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <input id="secret" type="hidden">
  </form>
  <div class="field">
    <footer>Observe the hidden input's value thru
      <br/>the console. (<b>F12</b> then the <b>Console</b> tab).</footer>
    <script sr="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Zer00ne. I see what you have done but this doesn't solve my scenario, because this uses form fields for the quantity selection. If i wanted to use input fields i would do as CBroe mentioned and that would be easy. The scenario I have in relation to your answer needs to put the text value of the div #Counter into the hidden field secret. Where you have created a form and used number type inputs has thrown me and so I cant see how to adapt your code to make this work for me. Sorry for the delay in getting back to you

Comment: The jquery code I posted is populating the div.text with class .number when the - or + divs are clicked, what code can I add to the existing jquery to also populate the hidden field at the same time. The difference between referencing div.text and a form input confuses me as I do not know JS

Comment: `onchange` event fires on the condition that a **from element's** **value** changes. This will not work for a div. You must adapt to different ways of doing things. If you stick to using divs, you will be sorely limited.

Answer (score 0):

With pure JS:
document.getElementById("Num").value = < variable name >

With jQuery(not 100% sure)
$("Num").value(< variable name>)

Comment: Ive changed the hidden field to a text field and this is not working when .number (the quantity) is changed. In the above javascript I posted im assuming my var is newVal?

Comment: Yes, newVal is variable name. You have to add this line of code to your function. So each time when there will be a change it will be executed.

Comment: Is there a chance to have some other element with same ID on the page?

Comment: There are no duplicate IDs on the page, but even trying it as a class doesnt seem to work. if the above jquery that updates the div.text that has class of .number could be modified to update the hidden field ID at the same time would be the right way of doing it I assume. I tried naming the hidden field class .number as the div is also called but it wouldnt work and I so wish it was that simple. I really should learn more about JS :(

Comment: Did you try with pure JS?

Comment: like you posted above yes. I tried adding another line in the jquery I posted above for ID Num like the above but it didnt work either and it made the original quantity selector stop working.

Comment: i'll edit my question above to show all the form code and maybe itll help to solve where i am going wrong